# Android Application Advetisement

Tags: android, xml

In My Android Application I added a admob advertisement.And i added it to App store too.When i run it on two Samsung galaxy s3 phones and Advertisement is showing up correctly. But when I download it to Samsung galaxy s duos Advertisements are not showing up.I tried it on two s duos phones.Same result.No advertisement is showing up.It seems that according to the screen resolution ads will show up or not.But How can I set these to show up in every phone.Thanks in any help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/t2"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="#64B801"
    android:textColorHint="#64B801"
    android:hint="Type Password Here"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@layout/custombtnhoverlogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/url"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#64B801"
    android:text="Kanishka Yohan" />  

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/smllogo" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/url"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Ronin Solutions Development Team"
    android:textColor="#64B801" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the xml code of the ad.

Comment: please provide the code of the rest of the layout

Comment: I updated the question Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You must have something like that:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-YOURCODE"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

in your code try to change: android:layout_marginTop

Comment: Try to change means i have to give a different value or i have to remove that part?